# Date range comparison not working in Entity Framework 5

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have written a query in Entity Framework. Checking that the current date is between two dates in my database. But no result are being returned, even though date is in between.

Here is my code.

```
var coupon = db.COUPONs.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(c => 
                   c.COUPONCODE == "ICLMSC15958565" && 
                   c.COURSEID == 270 && 
                   c.ACTIVEFLAG == "Y" && 
                   c.REMAIN > 0 &&
                  (c.VALIDFROM.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date  &&
                   c.VALIDTO.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date));
```

My table:

[image]

Comment: Did you check what the SQL query that is sent to database looks like?

Comment: No how would i check that ? @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: You're querying for courseid 207. The table only contains 270

Comment: @Ric.Net that my posting mistake that was coming dynamicaly.

Comment: Why are you using AsEnumerable? Any specific reason to do this?

Comment: @Raghubar add a breakpoint before your code executes, start off SQL Profiler, and then run your code. The SQL statements that got generated will show you what the SQL query was.

Answer (score 1):

According to your data , ValidTo date is greater then Validfrom date in both the cases.
And according to your condition

```
    c.VALIDFROM.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date  &&
    c.VALIDTO.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date
```

so by this condition if "DateTime.Now.Date >= c.VALIDTO.Value.Date" then 'DateTime.Now.Date' will definetlly be greater then 'c.VALIDFROM.Value.Date' 
As per your data. so it wont satisfy  "c.VALIDFROM.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date "
condition

Comment: Yes it was my condition mistake and i had resolved it.